# How do I use R cut function to create custom bins with x y coordinates?

Tags: r, cut

Firstly apologies, if I do not explain this very well, I'm relatively new to the cut function and cannot find a suitable answer to my question.

I have X Y coordinate data, and I know how to create evenly distributed bins for use with stat_bin_2d. I would do something like this:

```
heatmap$xbin <- cut(heatmap$x, breaks = seq(from=0, to=100, by = 20),include.lowest=TRUE )
heatmap$ybin <- cut(heatmap$y, breaks = seq(from=0, to=100, by = 20),include.lowest=TRUE)
```

Using ggplot I'd include this in a plot like so:

`stat_bin_2d(data = heatmap, aes(x=x, y=y), binwidth = c(20,20))+`

However if I want to create custom sized bins of different sizes, I'm not entirely sure how I do this. For example, if I wanted to plot specific zones of interest on a sports pitch, how do I approach the cut function as its not an even distribution?

[image]

I tried this, but again I don't believe this is correct:

```
heatmap$xbin <- cut(heatmap$x, breaks = seq(from=80, to=100, by = 1),include.lowest=TRUE )
heatmap$ybin <- cut(heatmap$y, breaks = seq(from=40, to=60, by = 1),include.lowest=TRUE)
```

Effectively I'd like bins like this, once I know how to customize the bins sizes:

[image]

Comment: In ggplot, x and scales are usually independent on each other. Do you need to model the circles? I would work with shapefiles because this is spatial data. Fields 1-4 seems to be nested besides 7. This would not possible with cut, because now x depends on y.

Comment: I would also go for polygons using the `sf`-package. to complicate things: the size of a soccer pitch may vary from stadium to stadium... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Football_pitch

Comment: The points were all in interval [0,100] so you can convert every coord to percentages using `x/max(x)*100`

Comment: @danlooo thanks for your comment, no the circles dont need to be included just the boxes. What does converting the coords to a % do different to numerical coordinates?

Comment: it allows you to account for differences between soccer fields. they should be fairly standardized but (as @Wimpel points out) they may vary by some margin regradless

Comment: @D.J ah thanks, I see. The data is already standardized to one scale.